# How to get assign values to an arraylist item inside a cursor iterator

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, cursor

I am trying to assign one variable to an ArrayList item inside a cursor but it always returns me last value. Here is the code below.

**Getting value from DB**

```
 public ArrayList<Bean> getPendingData(String s) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {name};
    String[] selectionArgs = {s};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, " pending= ? ", selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();       
    ArrayList<Bean> pending = new ArrayList<>();
    String index0 = null;
    Bean bean;
    bean = new Bean();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        index0 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(name));
        bean.setQuestion(index0);
        pending.add(bean);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return pending;
}
```

**Bean.java**

```
public class Bean {
public static int id; // ans
public static String score;
public static String logo;
public static String image;

public static String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public static void setQuestion(String question) {
    Bean.question = question;
}

public static String question;
public static String description;
public static String option_three;
public static String OptionFour;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your bean inside the while block:

```
while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    Bean bean = new Bean();
    index0 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(name));
    bean.setQuestion(index0);
    pending.add(bean);
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

The reason is that Java uses objects by reference, so you're always adding the same object to the array "pending", but in following iterations you're changing the value of this object, so finally you have the value of the last iteration.

Comment: Nothing change Igor, it is returning the last value only.

Comment: Could you try this code? Instead of while block:
`do {
    Bean bean = new Bean();
    String index0 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(name));
    bean.setQuestion(index0);
    pending.add(bean);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());`
There you can as well add a breakpoint to debug the values given in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.isAfterLast()` returns `true` when cursor is at last row position. Adding a `!` (not) means perform till it is not at the end of cursor.

so `while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){}` means while loop will traverse till last record of cursor.

Use this method to fetch all rows returning from cursor.

```
if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                homeClassesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                do {
                   // fetching data
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Nothing change Dharmistha , it is returning the last value only.